# Time ordering in the definition of the single-particle Green function

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, field-theory, greens-functions

The following form of the single-particle Green's function for a fermionic system is often seen in the literature:

$$ G(x, t) = -i \theta(t) \langle \psi(x,t) \psi^\dagger (0,0)\rangle + i \theta(-t) \langle \psi^\dagger(0,0) \psi(x, t) \rangle,  $$

where $\theta $ is the Heaviside step function.

By this definition, $G$ is a piece-wise function of $t$. This implies some discontinuity at $t = 0$, and that is very annoying. Of course one should prefer a single continuous function.

Hence, why should people consider $G $ such defined, but not simply the more elegant function

$$ F(x , t) =  \langle \psi(x,t) \psi^\dagger (0,0)\rangle,   $$

which at least looks more smooth?

Comment: Because the $G(x,t)$ satisfy the definition of Green's function (you can check using the euqation of motion), the $F$ you defined does not satisfy.

Comment: Could you be more specific? For what purposes do we need G but not F?

Comment: You can check: $i\hbar \partial_t G(t,t';x,x') - \int dx_1 \  H(x,x_1)G(t,t';x_1,x')=\delta(t,t')\delta(x-x')$, which is the definition of Green's function.

Comment: Just one more thing, the GF you mentioned in your problem is the so-called time-ordered GF, there are also other types, e.g. Retarded GF and Advanced GF, you can easily find the definition of them in many textbooks on condensed matter physics, like [Mahan](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780306463389) or [Flensberg](https://www.amazon.com/Many-Body-Quantum-Theory-Condensed-Physics/dp/0198566336).